# How to make image to fit inside the container with padding and margin set?

Tags: html, css

I have the css code below which defines the `body-content` wrapper class, and I need images to fit inside the wrapper, but they are extending out of it.

I tried setting `overflow` on the wrapper to be `auto` but that doesn't work either.

```css
body {
    background-color:#231f20;
}
.body-content {
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:50px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
   
}

div.logoimg{
   background-image: url( https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3XY6.png);
   width:291px; 
   height:65px;
  
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   float: left;
   overflow: auto;

}
.largeimg{

   background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B2Un.jpg);
   width:1460px; 
   height:369px;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   background-size: 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;

   z-index: -1;
   overflow: auto;/*hidden;*/
   position: relative;
   display: block;
}
    .menu{
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    padding-left:20px;
    background-color: #231f20;
    float:left;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.menu ul li {
    float: left;

}
.menu ul li  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color:#231f20;
    color:  #ffd41b;
} 
.menu ul li a:hover{
     display: block;
     background-color: #ffd41b;
     color:  #231f20;
}
.menu ul li.icon {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="body-content">
        <div class="logoimg"></div>
        <div class="menu" id="myMenu">

            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "Index", "About")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="largeimg"></div>
```

This resulting page looks like this:[image]

I need images to be responsive and to fit inside the container with paddings and margins like this:
[image]

I tried was searching the internet for a solution but I found only the overflow suggestion which didn't work.

How do I get the images to stay inside the container?

Comment: Can you include the rest of the relevant code, or include a link to a working demo so that we can see the issue in action please?

Comment: I added the css code of the menu what else?

Comment: Whatever it takes to get the code snippet working so that we can see the problem :)

Comment: I don't know how to put images into this snipet for css code

Comment: Is all the rest of the CSS and HTML complete - is it supposed to look like it does when you run the snippet? Alternatively, could you include a link to the working page?

Comment: I don't have a link it is on my local machine

Comment: Without seeing whats actually happening, I'm afraid we are unlikely to be able to help. If you could recreate it in the snippet or even a jsfiddle or codepen or similar, that would help.

Comment: on the snippet Works I don't know what is problem :(((

Comment: The code you have added is working so its obviously so other code thats affecting your live site. Do you have any other CSS or includes? Its hard to work out whats happening without seeing the live page myself. In your local site, use the element inspector to see what other css is getting applied to each element and see if you can figure it out that way. Or try deleting our the rest of the css and/or includes css and adding it back bit-by-bit to identify what part is causing the problem. Hopefully that might help you locate the problem.

Comment: Oh It Works on chrome but on iexplorer not becouse I have older version
How to fix to work on iexplorer too?

Comment: The dreaded old IE browsers :) Well the code snippet works in IE11 if that helps.

Comment: Oh my god it is working on ie too but I needed to refresh it becouse it loads cach code ... stupid...

Comment: Glad you sorted it :)